# Moody's, S&P, Fitch revenues per country

Tags: credit-ratings

I need a variable which identifies the possible conflict of interests between credit rating agencies and countries, although they do not pay in order to be rated.
Such a variable could be the proportion of income coming from each country, namely how many national private companies or banks or other financial institutions pay the CRAs for their services.
Do you think I can find such data on the agencies' balancesheet, maybe they divide the revenues for market segment?

Or other Ideas are welcomed! :)

Answer (score 2):

Since only Moody's is quoted please find below what I could find on BBG for Moody's:

[image]

If it is on Bloomberg, then you can find it in its balance-sheet. Have fun :)